# Product of spinors in Dirac field anticommutators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, spinors, anticommutator

I am reading a "A modern introduction to quantum field theory" by Maggiore and on page 88 it shows the anticommutators of the Dirac field:

$$
\{\psi_a(\vec{x},t),\psi_{b}^{\dagger}(\vec{y},t)\}=\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{y})\delta_{ab}.
$$

So I am trying to calculate it using the anticommutators for creation and destroy operator for particle and antiparticle:

$$
\{a_{\vec{p}}^{r},{a_{\vec{q}}^{s}}^\dagger\} = \{b_{\vec{p}}^{r},{a_{\vec{q}}^{s}}^\dagger\}= (2\pi)^3\delta(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\delta^{rs}
$$

and the expression for the Dirac field:

$$
\psi(x)=\int {d^3p\over (2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E_p}}\sum_{s=1,2}\left({a_{\vec{p}}^{s}} u^s(p)e^{-ipx} + {b_{\vec{p}}^{s}}^\dagger v^s(p)e^{ipx}\right)
$$

where $u^s(p)$ and $v^s(p)$ are spinors and $s=1,2$ denote one of the two linear independent spinors

In calculating the filed aunticommutator I encounter products of the spinors, like  $u^s(p)\bar u^r(q)$,  and I am unsure about what is meant to be this product, cause if it were the usual scalar product of two vectors then I can't obtain the expected anticommtutator expression.

In the same book on page 61 it reports various formulas for $\bar u u$ and $u\bar u$, and mentions that $\bar u u$ is a complex number, while $u\bar u$ is a 4x4 matrix, but it doesn't give any details of the reason.

I desperately looked in other books and in "Quantum field theory" by Schwartz at page 191 he mentions that $u\bar u$ is a **spinor outer product**. I Looked for outer product in wikipedia and realized that is an easy kind of product that given two vectors it returns a matrix.

So am I correct to assume that when I have expression like $\psi\bar\psi$ the product of the spinor is meant to be an outer product?

When calculating the anticommutator of the Dirac filed I have terms like the following:

$$
\{{a_{\vec{p}}^{s}} u^s(p),{{a_{\vec{q}}^{r}}^\dagger} \bar u^r(q)\}= {a_{\vec{p}}^{s}} {{a_{\vec{q}}^{r}}^\dagger} u^s(p)\bar u^r(q) + {{a_{\vec{q}}^{r}}^\dagger} {a_{\vec{p}}^{s}}\bar u^r(q) u^s(p)
$$

If $\bar u^r(q) u^s(p)$ is a complex number I can't get the correct expression for Dirac field anticommutator, I can get the correct expression if it's an 4x4 matrix as $ u^s(p) \bar u^r(q)$.
That's why it seems that in expression like $\psi\bar\psi$ the product of the spinor is meant always to be an outer product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the relations $$ \sum\limits_s u_a^s(p) \bar{u}_b^s(p) =(p \! \! \! /+m \, \mathbb{I})_{ab} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum\limits_s v_a^s(p) \bar{v}_b^s(p) = (p \! \! \! /-m \, \mathbb{I})_{ab},$$ where $a,b$ are Dirac indices.

Comment: I know I have to use that formula, my concern was about how to get it and what is that product. Also because when calculating anticommutator you have also expression like $\bar u u$ and the author say $\bar u u$ is different from $ u \bar u$. May guess is that in this calculation both $\bar u u$ and $ u \bar u$ are meant to be outer product, with that assumption I can get the correct anticommutator for field

Comment: @Andrea $\bar{u}  u \equiv \sum\limits_a \bar{u}_a u_a$ is a complex number and $u \bar{u}$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix (in Dirac space) with matrix elements $u_a \bar{u}_b$. The derivation of the formulas given in my answer can be found in any  text-book on particle physics or quantum field theory.

Comment: @ Hyperon when I calculate the Dirac filed anticommutator I have both $\bar u u$ and $u \bar u$, as far as I can see if I use the complex number for $\bar u u$ I can't get the usual anticommutator for field. So even for $\bar u u$ terms I have to use the relation that is a 4x4 matrix

Comment: @Andrea Writing all formulae with explicit Dirac indices present avoids any confusion. Once you write e.g. $u$ (without indices) it is meant to be a $4 \times 1$ matrix = a vector (in Dirac space) and $\bar{u}$ is a $1 \times 4$ matrix. Consequently $\bar{u} u$ is $1 \times 1$ and $u \bar{u}$ is $4 \times 4$.

Comment: I believe I have understood what you are explaining and I agree, but my point is that $\bar u u$ can't be a complex number when calculating the ainticommutator. I have edit the post to add some details and make more clear my concern.

Comment: @Andrea I can only repeat what  I had said already: Attach  Dirac indices when you compute the anti-commutator $\{\psi_a(t, \vec{x}), \psi_b^\dagger (t, \vec{y})\}$ and all "problems" disappear.